# Angular Compiler was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class. cant build the project

Tags: angular, typescript

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4llK.png)

Angular Compiler was detected but it was an instance of the wrong class.
This likely means you have several @ngtools/webpack packages installed. You can check this with `npm ls @ngtools/webpack`, and then remove the extra copies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your angular packages are on the same version.
When you update your `packages.json` file to have the same versions delete your `nodes_modules` directory and run `npm install`.

When starting the angular project use `npm start`. When you use `ng serve` the global version of the angular CLI is triggered. If you want to use `ng serve` I would also make sure that the global angular cli version matches that of the project.